# call a script automatically in container before docker stops the container

Tags: bash, docker

I want a custom bash script in the container that is called automatically before the container stops (`docker stop` or `ctrl + c`).

According to [this docker doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/) and multiple StackOverflow threads, I need to catch the `SIGTERM` signal in the container and then run my custom script when the event appears. As I know `SIGTERM` can be only used from a root process with `PID 1`.

**Relevand part of my `Dockerfile`:**

```
...
COPY container-scripts/entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I use `[]` to define the `entrypoint` and as I know this will run my script directly, without having a `/bin/sh -c` wrapper (`PID 1`), and when the script eventually exec another process, that process becomes the main process and will receive the docker stop signal.

**entrypoint.sh:**

```
...
# run the external bash script if it exists
BOOT_SCRIPT="/boot.sh"
if [ -f "$BOOT_SCRIPT" ]; then
    printf ">> executing the '%s' script\n" "$BOOT_SCRIPT"
    source "$BOOT_SCRIPT"
fi

# start something here
...
```

The `boot.sh` is used by child containers to execute something else that the child container wants. Everything is fine, my containers work like a charm.

**`ps axu` in a child container:**

```
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 {entrypoint.sh} /bin/bash /entrypoint.sh
  134 root      0:25 /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin/java -server -D...
  ...
  421 root      0:00 ps axu
```

Before stopping the container I need to run some commands automatically so I created a `shutdown.sh` bash script. This script works fine and does what I need. But I execute the shutdown script manually this way:

```
$ docker exec -it my-container /bin/bash
# /shutdown.sh
# exit

$ docker container stop my-container
```

I would like to automate the execution of the `shutdown.sh` script.

I tried to add the following to the entrypoint.sh but it does not work:

```
trap "echo 'hello SIGTERM'; source /shutdown.sh; exit" SIGTERM
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: It would help a lot if you built a [mre] that replaces your Java program with something like, say, `sleep 60` -- the goal is to let people test their answers.

Comment: That said -- to understand your problem, compare `(shell_pid=$BASHPID; set -x; trap 'echo "caught"' SIGUSR1; sleep 60 & mainpid=$!; (sleep 1 & kill -USR1 $shell_pid) & wait "$mainpid")` with `(shell_pid=$BASHPID; set -x; trap 'echo "caught"' SIGUSR1; (sleep 1 & kill -USR1 $shell_pid) & sleep 60)`. You'll see that the signal isn't immediately handled when something else is in the foreground.

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to source BOOT_SCRIPT, rather than running it as a subprocess? (Sure, you can source something in a subshell in the background and `wait` for that subshell, akin to `wait`ing for a `sleep` in the example above, but doing so gives up some of the benefits of using `source` in the first place, so there's value in trying to understand why that was the initial design).

Comment: (What are these scripts?  Can you do the relevant cleanup work directly in the process, rather than a Docker-specific wrapper?  What would happen if the container exited without running the script?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your help and comments guided me in the right direction.
I went through again the official documentations [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/), and [here](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/trap.1p.html) and finally I found what was the problem.

**The issue was the following:**

My `entrypoint.sh` script, which kept alive the container executed the following command at the end:

```
# start the ssh server
ssh-keygen -A
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -e "$@"
```

The `-D` option runs the ssh daemon in a NOT detach mode and `sshd` does not become a daemon. Actually, that was my intention, this is the way how I kept alive the container.

But this foreground process prevented to be executed properly the `trap` command. I changed the way how I started the `sshd` app and now it runs as a normal background process.

Then, I added the following command to keep alive my docker container (this is a recommended best practice):

```
tail -f /dev/null
```

But of course, the same issue appeared. `Tail` runs as a foreground process and the `trap` command does not do its job.

The only way how I can keep alive the container and let the `entrypoint.sh` runs as a foreign process in docker is the following:

```
while true; do
    sleep 1
done
```

This way the `trap` command works fine and my bash function that handles the `SIGINT`, etc. signals runs properly when the time comes.

But honestly, I do not like this solution. This endless loop with a `sleep` looks ugly, but I have no idea at the moment how to manage it in a nice way :(

But this is another question that not belongs to this thread (but could be great if you can suggest my a better solution).